# Нужна помощь с C++

Tags: c++, массивы

Почему выводится адрес, а не числа?

вот пример:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(void)
{
    int x,y;
    int numbers[10][10] = 
    {{1,2,3,2,7,1,8,1,6},
    {4,7,4,2,8,9,2,5,8},
    {4,9,3,3,6,2,8,4,2},
    {1,2,3,6,2,6,8,2,1}};

    for(x = 0;x < 10;x++){
        cout << *(numbers + x);
        for(y = 0;y < 10;y++){
            cout << *(numbers + y);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: … потому что вы выводите адрес, а не числа.

Comment: Если будете разыменовывать  for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) { cout << **(numbers + x); } получите первый столбец, половина элементов которых неинициализированы(будут иметь значение по умолчанию)

Answer (score 6):

- `numbers` имеет тип `int [10][10]`
- В данном контексте тип `numbers` неявно преобразуется к типу `int (*)[10]`
- Тип `numbers + i` - тоже `int (*)[10]`
- Соответственно тип `*(numbers + i)` - это `int [10]`
- В данном контексте тип `int [10]` неявно преобразуется к типу `int *`
- Именно этот `int *` вы и выводите. Потому и выводится адрес.

Другими словами, в вашем примере адрес выводится по той же самой причине, по которой выводится адрес в

```
int a[10];
std::cout << a << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 5):

Вот такой код

```
int x;
int numbers[10][20];
cout << typeid(numbers).name() << endl;
cout << typeid(*(numbers+x)).name() << endl;
```

в VC++ выдает

```
int [10][20]
int [20]
```

Т.е. разыменование работает по первой размерности, выдавая одномерный массив...

Понятно, что для него выводится адрес.